# Google browser SSH or regular shell to access Compute Engine instances?

Tags: shell, ssh, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run "fastq-dump" from the "SRA Toolkit" to download and extract genomic data from NCBI servers. I have set up a GCE instance, installed the program on the root volume, and attached/mounted an extra volume where I am planning to keep the resulting files. Each extraction results in two ~11GB files and takes about 30 minutes on the basic instance that I've set up.

Now, if I access my instance through the "easy" way, which is the Google browser shell, the connection is almost always interrupted before one extraction is completed. It seems like the process also stops, output files are incomplete, and a bunch of space on the root volume (where fastq-dump is located) is left occupied by hidden file monsters (the 4.6G below).

```
user@basic-machine:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G  4.6G   24G  17% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           743M  8.3M  735M   2% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb        197G   83G  104G  45% /home/user/datavol
```

Instead, if I make my own SSH keys and connect to the instance through my own shell, the process always completes AND I seem to utilize much more CPU capacity. The first peak below is by the browser shell, and the second peak is through my own SSH connection:

[Comparing CPU usage when I use the Google browser shell and Mac shell to run the same software on GCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDVER.png)

Now my question is, why would running the same command produce different results depending on what shell you use? And what's the benefit of using the Google browser shell if any at all?